# Align right is not working

Tags: css, alignment, css-selectors

I am using the inuit.css framework and added a [css file](https://github.com/metaperl/cleartrader/blob/master/public/css/my.css) which contains a right-alignment directive but the text "About | FAQ | Getting Started | Forum | Chat" is not aligned to the right.

**CSS:**

```
align_right {
 text-align: right;
}
```

The entire website comes directly [from source control](https://github.com/metaperl/cleartrader)

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: add a dot (.) in the css file for align_right to be .align_right

Comment: Please give a cut down version via JSFiddle.com . I doubt if any one will go through the entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you miss the `class` dot `.` so, you have write like this

```
.align_right {
 text-align: right;
}
```